# Selenium does not grab text around some html tags that show it only when clicking an icon

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

please consider this code:

```
**<div class="table-list"** id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_218">
    <div class="list-heading hidden-phone" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_247">
        <div style="width: 26%;" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_246"> Pratica </div>
        <div style="width: 36%;"> Dettagli </div>
        <div style="width: 38%;" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_265"> Soggetti </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-big-row row-odd" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_217">
        <div class="list-heading visible-phone">
            <div> Pratica </div>
        </div>
        <div class="list-big-row-cell dettaglio-vert dettaglio-vert1" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_232">
            <section class="list-section" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_231">
                <div class="row-fluid riga" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_240">
                    <div class="span12 " id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_239">
                        <div class="popupAncestor" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_244">
                            **<div class="popup hide">**
                                <div class="row-fluid rigaPopup" id="">
                                    <div class="span3 " id=""> <span class="indentatodescrizione">Numero</span> </div>
                                    <div class="span9 " id=""> <b> 1 </b> </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row-fluid rigaPopup" id="">
                                    <div class="span3 " id=""> <span class="indentatodescrizione">Anno</span> </div>
                                    <div class="span9 " id=""> <b> 2024 </b> </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row-fluid rigaPopup" id="">
                                    <div class="span3 " id=""> <span class="indentatodescrizione">Data apertura</span> </div>
                                    <div class="span9 " id=""> <b> 03/01/2024 </b> </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row-fluid rigaPopup" id="">
                                    <div class="span3 " id=""> <span class="indentatodescrizione">Data chiusura</span> </div>
                                    <div class="span9 " id=""> <b> - </b> </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row-fluid rigaPopup" id="">
                                    <div class="span3 " id=""> <span class="indentatodescrizione">Codice cartella</span> </div>
                                    <div class="span9 " id=""> <b> 2024/AB/000001 </b> </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row-fluid riga-header" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_243">
                                <div class="span3 span-sm-10" id=""> <i>Pratica</i> </div>
                                <div class="span9 span-sm-2" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_242"> <a title="Ulteriori dettagli" href="javascript:void(0);" class="openPopup color-cyan-dark" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_241"> <span class="icon-search" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_245"></span> </a> </div>
                            </div>
                        </div> <span class="indentato" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_238">
                            <div class="row-fluid " id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_237">
                                <div class="span2 offset-sm-1 span-sm-6" id=""> <span class="indentatodescrizione">Numero</span> </div>
                                <div class="span6 span-sm-5" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_236" style="text-align: center;"> 1 </div>
                                <div class="span2 offset-sm-1 span-sm-6" id=""> <span class="indentatodescrizione">Anno</span> </div>
                                <div class="span2 span-sm-5" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_248" style="text-align: center;"> 2024 </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-fluid " id="">
                    <div class="span12 " id=""> </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-fluid riga" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_230">
                    <div class="span12 " id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_229">
                        <div class="popupAncestor" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_235">
                            <div class="popup hide">
                                <div class="row-fluid rigaPopup" id="">
                                    <div class="span3 " id=""> <span class="indentatodescrizione">Numero</span> </div>
                                    <div class="span9 " id=""> <b> 665 </b> </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row-fluid rigaPopup" id="">
                                    <div class="span3 " id=""> <span class="indentatodescrizione">Anno</span> </div>
                                    <div class="span9 " id=""> <b> 2024 </b> </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row-fluid rigaPopup" id="">
                                    <div class="span3 " id=""> <span class="indentatodescrizione">Data</span> </div>
                                    <div class="span9 " id=""> <b> 03/01/2024 </b> </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row-fluid riga-header" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_234">
                                <div class="span3 span-sm-10" id=""> <i>Protocollo</i> </div>
                                <div class="span9 span-sm-2" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_233"> <a title="Ulteriori dettagli" href="javascript:void(0);" class="openPopup color-cyan-dark"> <span class="icon-search"></span> </a> </div>
                            </div>
                        </div> <span class="indentato" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_228">
                            <div class="row-fluid " id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_227">
                                <div class="span2 offset-sm-1 span-sm-6" id=""> <span class="indentatodescrizione">Numero</span> </div>
                                <div class="span6 span-sm-5" id="" style="text-align: center;"> 665 </div>
                                <div class="span2 offset-sm-1 span-sm-6" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_226"> <span class="indentatodescrizione">Anno</span> </div>
                                <div class="span2 span-sm-5" id="" style="text-align: center;"> 2024 </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-fluid " id="">
                    <div class="span12 " id=""> </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-fluid riga" id="">
                    <div class="span12 " id="">
                        <div class="row-fluid riga-header" id="">
                            <div class="span3 span-sm-10" id=""> <i>Provvedimento</i> </div>
                            <div class="span9 span-sm-2" id=""> </div>
                        </div> <span class="indentato">
                            <div class="row-fluid " id="">
                                <div class="span2 offset-sm-1 span-sm-6" id=""> <span class="indentatodescrizione"> Data </span> </div>
                                <div class="span6 span-sm-5" id="" style="text-align: center;"> - </div>
                                <div class="span2 offset-sm-1 span-sm-6" id=""> <span class="indentatodescrizione"> Numero </span> </div>
                                <div class="span2 span-sm-5" id="" style="text-align: center;"> - </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="list-heading visible-phone">
            <div> Dettagli </div>
        </div>
        <div class="list-big-row-cell dettaglio-vert dettaglio-vert2" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_216">
            <div class="inside-row-cell-cont" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_263">
                <div class="inside-row-cell" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_262">
                    <section class="list-section" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_261"> <i>Tipologia</i> <span class="indentato" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_264"> Agibilità - Certificato di Agibilità </span> </section>
                </div>
            </div>
            <section class="list-section" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_215">
                <div class="row-fluid riga" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_214">
                    <div class="span12 span-sm-12" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_213"> <i id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_249">Oggetto</i> <span class="indentato" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_212"> RISTRUTTURAZIONE EDILIZIA DI FABBRICATO COSTITUITO DA n. 2 UNITA' IMMOBILIARI A DESTINAZIONE CIVILE ABITAZIONE SITO IN PISA CAPOLUOGO VIA S. AGOSTINO n. 311 - 313 ai sensi Art. 135, Comma 2, Lett. "D" - L.R. 65/2014 Foglio 46, particella 722, sub. 17 e 19. S.C.I.A. 2021/EP/002045 - prot. 54448 del 28/05/2021 </span> </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="list-section" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_250">
                <div class="row-fluid riga" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_254">
                    <div class="span12 " id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_253">
                        <div id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_252">
                            <div class="row-fluid " id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_251">
                                <div class="span3 span-sm-10" id=""> <i>Ubicazioni&nbsp;(2)</i>&nbsp; </div>
                                <div class="span9 span-sm-2" id=""> </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="span-sm-12" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_256"> <span class="indentato" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_255"> VIA SANT'AGOSTINO , 313 </span> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="list-heading visible-phone">
            <div> Soggetti </div>
        </div>
        <div class="list-big-row-cell dettaglio-vert" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1704287955572_257">
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Selenium can grab text found except what is inside that div class "popup-hide"

I managed to grab all contents of div class "table-list" with this code:

```
html_grezzo = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"table-list")
html_grezzo2 = [str(elem.text) for elem in html_grezzo]
```

This data should contain the text inside div "popup-hide" but it's not shown maybe because this code is called by a js function which knows the right id which constantly changes.

Because of the constant id change, the only way to catch all text inside the html tags, I think, is to look inside div tags. Am I wrong?

What do you suggest to grab all data even that inside the div class "popup-hide" ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the whole dom is accessible by selenium.
If not then try scroll_to(element). and then try to get text

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I believe it's not a matter of scrolling. By default text inside the div class=popup-hide is not shown until user clicks on a lens icon that recall a javascript procedure marked with an id that constantly changes. Could be this the reason?

Comment: Have you tried clicking and then grabing text?

Comment: As I wrote previously, clicking that icon trough Selenium means knowing the associated id to the div tag that contains the javascript call that display that text. Do you mean should I press that icon to make the text visible and then run the complete page divs grab?

Comment: I wonder why you are not using class for clicking instead of id?